# Samsung Galaxy Book S (Intel) - Ubuntu 20.1 cannot get keyboard/mousepad to work

Tags: keyboard, samsung

Dear friendly community :-),

installed Ubuntu on the Samsung Galaxy Book S (Intel) using a SD card and a keyboard connected via USB. Works ok'ish. But I couldn't get the keyboard/mouse of the laptop to work at all. Makes it all a bit meaningless - any ideas on how to make these work?

Thanks a lot,

Andreas

Comment: Hi and welcome. There is no Ubuntu version 20.1 there is a 20.10 and a 20.04

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the Intel I2C PCIe device is not recognized by the kernel presently. According to the device manager in winderz both he track pad and keyboard are I2C HID devices attached Intel I2C PCIe device. As Linux isn't recognizing that adapter it can't see the track pad or keyboard.

**Update:** A patch has now been accepted that fixes this:

https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-gpio/msg66048.html